# Added Angular's artifacts (Build) into spring boot project not working

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I worked separate Angular project(runs on port:4200) and created a build of the same (by ng build --prod) and trying to add that build into separate spring boot project (runs on port:8080) under, src->main->resource->static to make it as a single deployable jar. But on running that spring boot project which contains Angular build into it, localhost:4200 is not reachable and I am not able to get any angular project's URL. [find the structure of my project with angular build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1yWs.png)

Comment: When you bundle angular application with spring boot, run your application with spring boot port. e.g. localhost:8080

Comment: I am able to run only REST APIs on localhost:8080 and angular's URL is giving Whitelabel Error Page message

Comment: What is angular url? For which ur getting error?

Comment: @Plochie,  for index.html